# lmer with psycholinguistic data with R

Tags: r, simulation, lme4, montecarlo

I´m doing an Eye-Tracking study and I would like to determine the sample required to detect a power of 80%.
I have a pilot data spreadsheet with two participants.
It looks like this

[image]

I would like to make a mixed effect model out of it. What I would like to determine is if the condition (block) influences the reaction times (ia_rt) of participants reading a word.
Each word in the spreadsheet is linked to a reaction time and to the number of the specific sentence (sent_num).
I used the condition as the fixed effect and the stimuli (sent_num) and the participants as random effects.

So I wrote `RT_lmer_BRY2 <- lmer(ia_rt~block + (1|sent_num) + (1|participant), data = pilot_data`

Do you think that the formula is good for this kind of analysis? I´m now running the powerSim but it´s taking forever (the spreadsheet does have 1900+ rows though)..

Thank you, and forgive me inexperience with R and statistics!

Comment: It seems somewhat fine. One could argue that `sent_number` should be a fixed effect according to classic standards, but as the main effect of interest is `block` newer arguments would tend toward letting it be random. It does seem however that `block` is numeric, and according to your description it seems this that this should be a factor so you could evaluate the effect across difference blocks and not just the effect of changing from block level by "1". Use `I(factor(block))` in your formula or alter the original data in R, before running `lmer`.

Comment: I'd say you probably have enough observations for that model, but I'd wait for the results of the powerSim. Just make sure you set the method to Kenward-Roger or Satterthwait, because the others have been shown to be anti-conservative.

Comment: Hi both of you, thank you for your answer! The factor was indeed a problem.